# How to concatenate bit columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Seems like an easy question but I'm running into an odd error.  I have a large dataframe with 24+ columns that all contain 1s or 0s.  I wish to concatenate each field to create a binary key that'll act as a signature.

However, when the number of columns exceeds 12, the whole process falls apart.

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(3,12))
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.astype(int)   # This converts each 0.0  into just 0
df[2]=1               # Changes one column to all 1s

#result

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Concatenating function...

```
df['new'] = df.astype(str).sum(1).astype(int).astype(str)  # Concatenate
df['new'].apply('{0:0>12}'.format)                         # Pad leading zeros
# result
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  new
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   001000000000
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   001000000000
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   001000000000
```

This is good.  However, if I increase the number of columns to 13, I get...

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(3,13))
# ...same intermediate steps as above...


    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  new
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   00-2147483648
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   00-2147483648
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   00-2147483648
```

Why am I getting -2147483648?  I was expecting 0010000000000

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? This works for me, and the resultant column has int64 type.

Comment: @coldspeed, I'm using 0.23.4

Comment: try with  `a = np.zeros(shape=(3,13), dtype=np.int64)` instead. Looks like it is a data overflow, so force your numpy array to int64.